# Not able to get the relevant value from array, getting Uncaught TypeError "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length"

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to get the relevant value from the array for the selected option.

My select:

```
<select id="BestMobileSelect">
    <option></option>
    <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola>Motorola</option>
    <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Samsung>Samsung</option>
    <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Xiaomi>Xiaomi</option>
</select>
```

The Array:

```
var BestMobileJSON = {
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola" : [{"Price":"Rs.12000"}],
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Samsung" : [{"Price":"Rs.15000"}],
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Xiaomi" : [{"Price":"Rs.9000"}],
}
```

The jquery I'm using to get the relevant value is as below:

```
$("#BestMobileSelect").on("change", function () {
        var BestMobileSelected = $(this).val()

        var markup = '';
        jQuery.each(BestMobileSelected, function(index, value){
            markup += '<div>' + BestMobileJSON[value][0].Price +'</div>'
        });

    $("#BestMobileResult").html(markup);
    });
```

However, this is not working and Im getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola`

Why is this not working?

Find below complete code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var BestMobileJSON = {
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola": [{
      "Price": "Rs.12000"
    }],
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Samsung": [{
      "Price": "Rs.15000"
    }],
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Xiaomi": [{
      "Price": "Rs.9000"
    }],
  }

  $("#BestMobileSelect").on("change", function() {
    var BestMobileSelected = $(this).val()

    var markup = '';
    jQuery.each(BestMobileSelected, function(index, value) {
      markup += '<div>' + BestMobileJSON[value][0].Price + '</div>'
    });

    $("#BestMobileResult").html(markup);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="BestMobileSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola>Motorola</option>
  <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Samsung>Samsung</option>
  <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Xiaomi>Xiaomi</option>
</select>

<div id="BestMobileResult"></div>
```

Comment: The first argument to `$.each()` has to be an array or object. `BestMobileSelected` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `$.each()` must be an array or object, but `BestMobileSelected` is a string. You should use the dropdown value as an index into the `BestMobileJSON` object; this returns an array, and you can then loop over that array with `$.each()`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var BestMobileJSON = {
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola": [{
      "Price": "Rs.12000"
    }],
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Samsung": [{
      "Price": "Rs.15000"
    }],
    "Mobile-SmartPhone-Xiaomi": [{
      "Price": "Rs.9000"
    }],
  }

  $("#BestMobileSelect").on("change", function() {
    var markup = '';
    let val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
      var BestMobileSelected = BestMobileJSON[val];
      jQuery.each(BestMobileSelected, function(index, value) {
        markup += '<div>' + value.Price + '</div>'
      });
    }
    $("#BestMobileResult").html(markup);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="BestMobileSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Motorola>Motorola</option>
  <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Samsung>Samsung</option>
  <option value=Mobile-SmartPhone-Xiaomi>Xiaomi</option>
</select>

<div id="BestMobileResult"></div>
```